# Refresh screen from within BillingReceiver

Tags: android

I have an app comprised of multiple activities. There are multiple items that may be purchased. What is displayed within each activity may vary depending on what has been purchased. I have a `BillingReceiver` with a `purchaseStateChanged()` method. What I need to do inside `purchaseStateChanged()` is to say, whichever activity is running, please invalidate?/refresh? the screen. Is there a standard way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Looking at Simon's comment and just to make it easier to answer, let us say that when the BillingReceiver receives a call to purchaseStateChanged() one of two activities could be running, ActivityA or ActivtyB. These activities both contain methods `void redraw_everything()` which are both declared as:

```
void redraw_everything()
{
    getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();
}
```

I don't know the syntax for setting up a callback, but I guess the answer may look something like:

In onCreate of both activities we should say something like:

```
BillingReceiver.setupcallback(redraw_everything()); // ??
```

and in the onDestroy() methods have something like:

```
BillingReceiver.setupcallback(null); // ??
```

Then in BillingReceiver make a method something like:

```
??? stored_method_to_call;

void setupcallback(???? method_to_call)
{
     stored_method_to_call = method_to_call;
}
```

then inside purchaseStateChanged() have some code like:

```
if (stored_method_to_call != null) // ?? not sure about syntax
{
    stored_method_to_call(); // ?? not sure about syntax
}
```

Comment: Define an Interface and use callbacks from your BillingReceiver to your activity.  The activity registers an onPurchaseStateChangedListener() and responds as it needs to.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks, that looks like its probably correct, but I'm not comfortable enough with callbacks to get it running easily. So I've added some extra things to the question to make it easier to answer - and perhaps you could put your comment as an answer so you can get it marked as correct.

Comment: Done, with some sugar on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an interface and use a callback to let the activity know that a purchase has been made.

```
public Interface PurchaseStateChangedListener {
    void onPurchaseStateChanged();
}
```

In your billing receiver.

```
ArrayList<PurchaseStateChangedListener > listeners = new ArrayList<PurchaseStateChangedListener >();

...

public void setPurchaseStateChangedListener(PurchaseStateChangedListener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

In your purchase state change method:

```
for (PurchaseStateChangedListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onPurchaseStateChanged();
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements PurchaseStateChangedListener {

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ...

    billingReceiver.setPurchaseStateChangedListener(this);
    ...
}

public void onPurchaseStateChanged(){
   // do whatever you need to do
}
```

You could improve the billing receiver class by adding removePurchaseStateChangedListener and checking that you do not add the same listener twice in setPurchaseStateChangedListener.

Comment: Thank you. It all looks promising and I've got it all to compile (a few static's needed to be added). I'll give it the tick as soon as I've tested definitively that its working properly.